# How to get file information of list of files using C# and SMBLibrary

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am trying to get file information such as file name, last modified date/time and file size etc. from a list of Excel spreadsheet from a shared folder. I used C# and Tal Aloni's SMBLibary 1.4.8 to do that.

I need help to get the file information out from 'List' class fileList. Below is the program snippet working so far. I am able to logon the SMB server and connected to shared folder 'MPDS. The folder I working on have 9 Excel spreadsheet. When I printed out the 'fileList' element count, it returned 9 (the log statement: log.LogInformation("Number of fileList element: " + fileList.Count.ToString());).

I appreciated anyone giving me help or tips.

Note: I replaced the IP and the credential of the code snippet with a description.

```
var client = new SMB2Client();
bool isConnected = client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("<IP address>"), SMBTransportType.DirectTCPTransport);
if (isConnected)
{
    log.LogInformation("Connected to SMB");
    NTStatus status = client.Login("<domain>", "<user ID>", "<password>");
    if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Logged in as username");
        string filePath = @"Purchasing Admin\D365\Load Templates\Test Templates\" + cFileName + ".txt";
        ISMBFileStore fileStore = client.TreeConnect("MPDS", out status);
        status = fileStore.CreateFile(out object directoryHandle, out FileStatus fileStatus, @"Purchasing Admin\D365\Load Templates\Test Templates", AccessMask.GENERIC_READ, FileAttributes.Directory, ShareAccess.Read | ShareAccess.Write, CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN, CreateOptions.FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE, null);
        if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
            status = fileStore.QueryDirectory(out List<QueryDirectoryFileInformation> fileList, directoryHandle, "*.xlsx", FileInformationClass.FileDirectoryInformation);
            log.LogInformation("Number of fileList element: " + fileList.Count.ToString());

            status = fileStore.CloseFile(directoryHandle);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there with what you have in your provided code sample. You just need to inspect the files returned in your `fileList`, but need to cast to the appropriate `FileDirectoryInformation` type to get the file attributes you are seeking. For example:

```
if (status == NTStatus.STATUS_SUCCESS)
{
    List<QueryDirectoryFileInformation> fileList;
    status = fileStore.QueryDirectory(out fileList, directoryHandle, "*", FileInformationClass.FileDirectoryInformation);
    status = fileStore.CloseFile(directoryHandle);

    //
    // Here we are casting each item in the fileList to a FileDirectoryInformation 
    // type that holds the attributes you are looking for. 
    // 

    foreach(FileDirectoryInformation file in fileList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Filename: {file.FileName}");
        Console.WriteLine($"File Size: {file.AllocationSize / 1024}KB");
        Console.WriteLine($"Created Date: {file.CreationTime.ToString("f")}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Last Modified Date: {file.LastWriteTime.ToString("f")}");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();                            
    }
}
```

Note that I am just assuming that the file size you are looking for is in KB, but there are more advanced techniques to produce a better human readable size (you can check out libraries like [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#bytesize) etc.